# Outlook, Rules Wizard, search text which includes tab character?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm trying to search for `Changed by:{TAB}My Name` in the body of an email in the Outlook Rules Wizard. where {TAB} is a tab character.

However, it doesn't appear that it will let me enter a tab character.

I can't just search for two items, `Changed by:` and `My Name` as my name appears several times and changed by is a standard field.

I'm using MS Office 2010

Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Still looking for answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to embed a tab into the search string by pressing Control+i when entering it but this failed to match messages on my mail server. When I examined the actual characters in the message body of the received message I found that the {TAB} character had actual been translated into six \u00A0 (unicode) characters followed by a single space character. This prevented the search string from matching. You may want to try this method first to see if it works with your emails.

As an alternate solution, you can create a "custom" rule by adding a Visual Basic for Applications macro to Outlook.

1. First enable the Developer menu by going to **Outlook -> Options -> Customize Ribbon** and then checking off the **Developer** option in the *Main Tabs* list on the right.
2. Now back on the your main Outlook view you should see a **Developer** menu, select it
3. Click **Macro Security** button on the ribbon and select either "Notification for all macros" or "Enable all macros (not recommended; potentially dangerous code can run)
4. Next click the **Visual Basic** button on the ribbon to open the Visual Basic editor
5. Goto the **Tools -> References** and add a reference to the **Microsoft VBScript Regular Expression 5.5** library
6. In the Visual Basic editor, select **ThisOutlookSession** and paste the code listed below.
7. Save your project and exit Outlook
8. Reopen Outlook and send yourself a test message

You will need to edit the string contents of the *RouteToFolderName* and the *RouteToFolderRegEx* constants to match your search preferences.

The macro is saved to a file called **VBAProject.OTM** located in your user settings area (C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook\ folder on Windows 7). You may wish to make a backup copy of this file once you have gotten the macro working to your specifications.

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents olInboxItems As Items

' This is the name of the folder you want your messages moved to Private Const RouteToFolderName As String = "FollowUp"

' This is the regular expression that matches the text you are ' searching for. Outlook replaced a single {TAB} character with ' 6 x \u00A0 characters and 1 x space character. Private Const RouteToFolderRegex As String = "Changed By:\u00A0+\s+Me"

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim objNS As NameSpace
    Set objNS = Application.Session
    ' Attach the the Outlook inbox to receive an event whenever an item arrives
    Set olInboxItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
    Set objNS = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub olInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim objNS As NameSpace
    Dim objMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objMailFolderId As String
    Dim regex As RegExp
    Dim Found As Boolean
    
    ' Check to make sure we have a mail message first
    If (TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem) Then
    
        ' Locate the id of the folder we want to store the message in
        objMailFolderId = FindFolderByName(Application.Session.folders, Found, RouteToFolderName)
        
        Set objMailItem = Item
    
        Set regex = New RegExp
        regex.IgnoreCase = True  ' Do a case insensitive search
        regex.Global = True
        regex.Pattern = RouteToFolderRegex
    
        ' Test the message body against the regular expression
        If (regex.Test(objMailItem.Body)) Then
            ' Message body matched so move to our folder
            objMailItem.Move Application.Session.GetFolderFromID(objMailFolderId)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

' Recursively search from the root folder for the folder that matches "folderName" (case insensitive)
Public Function FindFolderByName(ByRef folders As Outlook.folders, ByRef Found As Boolean, ByVal folderName As String) As String
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder
        
    For Each objFolder In folders
        If Found = True Then
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        If LCase(objFolder.Name) = LCase(folderName) Then
            FindFolderByName = objFolder.EntryID
            Found = True
            Exit Function
        Else
            If objFolder.folders.Count > 0 Then
                FindFolderByName = FindFolderByName(objFolder.folders, Found, folderName)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for `Changed by:^tMy Name`.

If that doesn't work, try typing the whole search string, including the normal tab character, in WordPad, then cutting and pasting into search.

If that still doesn't work, then do the same thing but using [Advanced Find](http://www.howto-outlook.com/faq/locatefeature.htm).

Comment: Didn't work :(, I don't want to have to use advanced find each time

Answer (score 0):

You can enter a tab character from the keyboard by using the number pad with NumLock engaged. The ASCII hexadecimal code for the tab character is "09". Hold down the Alt key and type "09" on the number pad. When you release the Alt key a tab character is generated.